# Open google maps through app in safari in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I want to open the google maps through my app to get the direction with source address equal to my current location and destination address is my string.I have used the below code,i am able to open the app but not able to get the direction.

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=%@", [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

By using these line of code, i am able to open the app but the map is not taking the current location,destination address is there.

I have used this also by passing current location latitude and longitude but this also showing current location lat and long to 0.0000 both.

```
  NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%@",
                         coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude,
                         [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
NSString *coordinateString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", coordinate1.latitude, coordinate1.longitude];
NSString *coordinateString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", coordinate2.latitude, coordinate2.longitude];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",coordinateString1,coordinateString2]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: URL];
```

Comment: i want to show directions through current location to  a specified address string.

Comment: @Daij-Djan What do you mean apple maps? I run it on my phone and see google maps (the address is maps.google.com)

Comment: No problem.Though you did make me look at the address a few times.. :)

Comment: this code open a safari  browser but i want to open a google map app instead of safari via code

Comment: @amitgupta You can do that with the [Google Maps URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#google_maps_url_scheme_requests). If you're still having trouble after viewing the link please post a question and I'll try to help.

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: NICE! Worked out perfectly for me :)